# this is my code when i go to compile my SystemUI i keep getting a error parsing xml mismatched tag

Tags: android

Here i have a link instead 
https://app.box.com/s/srnw0q3d33syj8e90ybx

this is my code when i go to compile my SystemUI i keep getting a error parsing xml mismatched tag so i was wondering is there anything wrong with my code im sort of new to coding so i really need help

Comment: looks like you have a typo on line 5, some extra " f   f".  But it's hard to read with the formatting you have

Comment: oh sorry the original code doesnt have ff

Comment: also looks like you didn't close the *ViewFlipper* element

Comment: dont think that is the case

Comment: my code isnt being added i dont know how to add it

Answer (score 0):

After line 26, close the **ViewFlipper** tag.

Comment: oh it seemed to work looks like the original author made a mistake